# How to use two contexts for authentication and subscription in Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, react-router

I want to display the Stripe subscription form after user has signed up into the extension. I want to display home to a subscribed user. And whenever the user opens the extension the home should be displayed if he has already subscribed. If not, it should display subscription form.

But the problem is my app is displaying both the home and subscription form to a subscribed user.
Here is my private route code:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: RouteComponent, ...rest }) => {
  const { currentUser, subscriptionStatus } = useContext(AuthContext);
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(routeProps) =>
        !!currentUser ? (
          !!subscriptionStatus ? (
          <RouteComponent {...routeProps} />
          )
          : (
            <Redirect to={"/subscribe"} />
          )
          ) : (
          <Redirect to={"/login"} />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};
```

This is my auth context provider:

```
export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);
  const [pending, setPending] = useState(true);
  const [emailVerified, setEmailVerified] = useState(true);
  const [helper, setHelper] = useState(false);
  const [subscriptionStatus, setSubscriptionStatus] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    app.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async(user) => {
      setCurrentUser(user);
      if(!user.emailVerified){
        setEmailVerified(false);
      }else{
        setEmailVerified(true);
        const fetchData = async () => {
          const token = user && (await user.getIdToken());
          const payloadHeader = {
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            },
          };
          const status = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/is-subscribed', payloadHeader).then(r => r.json());
          if(status == 'active'){
            setSubscriptionStatus(status);
            setPending(false);
          }else{
            setPending(false);
          }
        }
        fetchData();
      }
    });
  }, []);

  if (pending && helper) {
    return <Loader />;
  }

  if(!emailVerified){
    return <>Please verify your email</>
  }

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        currentUser, subscriptionStatus
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Any idea on this?

Comment: When creating my extension, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44557946/3930351) useful to implement the subscriber access on Firebase, but take into account that SO is not an "I have an idea, please code it for me" kind of site.

Comment: I didn't ask for code. I'm looking for any thoughts on it.

Comment: Can you update your question to include all relevant code? The route looks like it should only render one of `RouteComponent` or either `Redirect` component. Can you share an example that is rendering the `Home` and subscription form components? Without seeing how they are being rendered it's ***very*** difficult to say why they may not be rendering correctly.

Comment: When the user is logged in and subscribed it is rendering the both components. Or else it is displaying the subscr form to an unsubcribed user. And login component to an anonymous user.

Comment: And I'm fetching subscription status from the backend.

Comment: @DrewReese What do you mean by relevant code?

Comment: You mentioned that a home component and a subscription form component were being rendered at the same time, so I was asking for you to update your question to show us how both of these components are being rendered so we can possibly see why both are rendered at the same time. If they are being rendered by this private route then it would also be helpful to see your auth context code/logic. This is part of including a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @DrewReese I just found out that it is due to the delay in fetching data from backend. How to make the authcontext wait until the subscription details is fetched from the backend?

Comment: Is this fetching logic in your `AuthContext`? Can you share that entire code?

Comment: @DrewReese Yes. See the updated question. I use helper and pending to avoid the immediate rendering of components. But it is still displaying the same behavior some times.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235577/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-axfg).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option would be [redirecting your customers to Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=checkout) to pay, and handling the successful payments in your Firebase app via webhooks, but you can also use the custom flow if you prefer.

Comment: I don't use Stripe Checkout. I'm using Stripe elements. And also my backend is Node.

Comment: My question is how to render component based on subscription status?. if not subscribed I want to display subscription form. Or home screen otherwise.

Comment: I would store the subscription status on your Firebase database (automatically from Stripe using webhooks as suggested) and read that status in your extension before rendering the HTML.

Comment: @IvánNokonoko Is it a good practice? is it safe?

Comment: @axfg It is what I am using. Make sure you process the payments in your backend and that you set up your Firebase database rules properly.